# Prove that for $\forall m, n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $[7(m + n)^2 + 2mn] \ \vdots \ 225$ then $mn \ \vdots \ 225$.

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that for $\forall m, n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $[7(m + n)^2 + 2mn] \ \vdots \ 225$ then $mn \ \vdots \ 225$.

This is taken directly from an exam my friend took on $03/06/2019$. I want to ask if there are any other solutions that are more practical.

Comment: what does $\vdots $ mean?

Comment: @WillJagy I guess that is the opposite of $\mid$, i.e., $a\vdots b$ iff $b\mid a$.

Comment: Please don't use (undefined) nonstandard notation when there is already adequate standard notation.

Comment: @BillDubuque as the matter of fact, it's not that uncommon. See comments under this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32501/how-to-get-a-good-divisible-by-symbol).

Comment: @QuangHoang It's extremely uncommon in my experience (in English mathematical text). In any case, if one is going to use rare notation then it shoudl at least be defined.

Comment: @BillDubuque Obviously, it's your call whether it is that someone horribly does not speak your Math language, or that you learn something new.

Comment: @QuangHoang This is an English language site. If you use notation that is rare in English then you should define it.

Comment: @BillDubuque My point is that OP is, judging on the question he asks, very likely a high school student in those countries where the notation is standard. There's no need to nitpicking on that given someone already explained it in the comment. It's just like a typo in a plain English paragraph. My apology if it's not your view.

Comment: @BillDubuque I know it's rare in English, but it's not that you couldn't find it. In your link, there's a text that uses the notation. But that's not my point. And I don't think it's a good idea to continue the conversation. Cheers.

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't think you realize just how rare such vertical ellipses are in English math. For example, Keith Conrad [wrote on HSM.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/who-invented-the-divisibility-symbol-and-why-is-it-backwards#comment9127_5662) "the only place I have ever seen that vertical three-dot notation is on blackboards in Russia. Where have you seen it in a published document?". One example is given there. I vaguely recall seeing it in a few Russian texts, but I don't recall ever seeing it used by native English speakers.

Comment: @QuangHoang  I edited and reposted my comment at the same time your reply arrived, You can delete and repost yours to get the correct temporal order. Note that the author (Alexey L. Gorodentsev) of the textbook cited there appears to be Russian (listed at Higher School of Economics in Moscow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $[7(m + n)^2 + 2mn] \ \vdots \ 225 \implies [4(7m^2 + 7n^2 + 16mn) - 225mn] \ \vdots \ 225$

$\implies (28m^2 + 28n^2 - 161mn) \ \vdots \ 225 \implies (4m^2 + 4n^2 - 23mn) \ \vdots \ 225$

$\implies [(7m^2 + 7n^2 + 16mn) + 2(4m^2 + 4n^2 - 23mn)] \ \vdots \ 225$

$\implies (15m^2 + 15n^2 - 30mn) \ \vdots \ 225 \implies (m - n)^2 \ \vdots \ 15 \implies (m^2 + n^2 - 2mn) \ \vdots \ 225$

$\implies [4(m^2 + n^2 - 2mn) - (4m^2 + 4n^2 - 23mn)] \ \vdots \ 225$

$\implies 17mn \ \vdots \ 225 \implies mn \ \vdots \ 225$

Note: Because $(7, 225) = (17, 225) = 1$, we can make simplifications like above. In addition, if $x \in \mathbb Z$ and $x^2 \ \vdots \ 15$ then we have that $x^2 \ \vdots \ 225$.

Comment: I have adjusted my solution to be true and more explainable.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$7(m + n)^2 + 2mn = 7 m^2 + 16 m n + 7 n^2 \equiv (m-n)^2 \bmod 3$$
$$7(m + n)^2 + 2mn = 7 m^2 + 16 m n + 7 n^2 \equiv 2(m-n)^2 \bmod 5$$

Therefore, $m\equiv n \bmod 15$. Write $m=15t+n$. Then
$$
7(m + n)^2 + 2mn = 30 n^2 + 450 n t + 1575 t^2 \equiv 30n^2 \bmod 225
$$
Thus,
$
30n^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 225
$
and so
$
2n^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 15
$,
which gives
$
n \equiv 0 \bmod 15
$.

Therefore, $m \equiv n \equiv 0 \bmod 15$ and $mn \equiv 0 \bmod 15^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 7 f = (7m+8n)^2 - 15 n^2 =  (8m+7n)^2 - 15 m^2  $$
For this to be divisible by $9$ and $25,$ it is first necessary that both $7m+8n$ and $8m+7n$ be divisible by both $3$ and $5,$ so that their squares are divisible by $9$ and $25.$ At this stage, we need both $15 n^2$ and $15 m^2$ to be divisible by $9$ and $25.$  It  follows that both $m,n$ are divisible by $3$ and $5.$ Thus $mn$ is divisible by $9$ and $25$

Comment: Your second to last statement is a little less obvious and need some clarification.